# Google Sheet Advanced Search using Query function

Tags: google-sheets, google-query-language

I'm trying to use Google Sheets to manage a database. I've figured out how to use the query function to do a simple search, but I'd like to know if an advanced search is possible. Here's what I mean:

[Example I made](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uqWeSng7nJQ4qnWZgqenBNcqsfWpxF8DLpLw_RexMF8/edit?usp=sharing) (refer to the second sheet)

Each row has a number of attributes, and the search sheet has a number of fields that can be entered. I'd like to be able to search for one without having to keep the other fields filled in as well, but I'm not sure how to mess around with the query function to get what I need.

Any help would be very much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: So you want [FILTER()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where must only appear at the beginning of the filtering, not before every conditional.
This can be done with FILTER and some if statements or keep the query and adjust it similarly like this:

```
= IFERROR(
    query(  
      Database!B3:G13,   
      "select B,C,D,E,F,G 
       where " &
         IF(LEN($C$4), "lower(C) contains lower('"&$C$4&"')", "1=1") & " and " &
         IF(LEN($E$4), "lower(D) contains lower('"&$E$4&"')", "1=1") & " and " & 
         IF(LEN($G$4), "lower(E) contains lower('"&$G$4&"')", "1=1") & " and " &
         IF(LEN($I$4), "lower(F) contains lower('"&$I$4&"')", "1=1") & " and " &
         IF(LEN($K$4), "lower(G) contains lower('"&$K$4&"')", "1=1")),
    "No Results")
```

It essentially checks if the filter is specified and if not puts 1=1 (TRUE) as a placeholder.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thank you!